# What is interface in magento 2 and why use?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

What is interface in Magento2 ? Why use this ? I want to know more detail about interface ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main use of Interface is :

> A public interface is a set of code that third-party developers can
> call, implement, or build as a plug-in. Magento guarantees that this
> code will not change in subsequent releases without a major version
> change.

You can read the detail information here :

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/api-concepts.html

Comment: Thank you Dhiren Vasoya

Comment: If answer help, upvote and accept as solution, so it will help other into community.